# Why does my wifi speed slow dramatically when more than one person uses it?

Tags: wireless-networking, router

Whenever both my roommate and I use the wifi in a certain room in our apartment, it slows dramatically for me. It doesn't slow for him. If he uses it in another room, it's fine; if I use it in another room together with him, it's fine; it's just in this particular room.

Does anyone know of a reason why this is?